# Bi-directional node parameters?

Tags: audiokit

I created a AudioEx node (custom DSP node in C), and I can pass parameters to it fine from the user interface.
Now I want to set parameters from within the DSP code and send them back to the UI (I use ParameterSlider UI objects). But this does not seem to work, I can never read these values from the calling high-level swift / UI code. Although if I do a parameter set/get from the DSP code, all seems fine.

Any idea how to do this ? thank you